# Set Active class to a specific li by label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I can set active class to a li by clicking it as

```
   $('.nav').on('click', 'li', function(){
   $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   });
```

Here I want to set the active class for a specific lable i.e for eg , I have my list as

```
 var list =["JHON" ,"Tom" ,"Dove", "Sam"]
```

and I want to set "Dove" as active  where it appear in the list.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="ls in List">{{ls}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The element of the List appears as each li

Comment: do u need to highlight the li's which are clicked ?

Comment: I want to highlight the li when the list is displayed

Comment: `ng-repeat` should `ng-repeat="ls in list"` and not `ng-repeat="ls in List"`, I'm sure that's a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

Since You are using [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) I would recommend you to to achieive it using Angular

*HTML*

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="ls in list" ng-class="{ 'active' : ls == selectedItem }" ng-click="activeMenu(ls)">{{ls}}</li>
    </ul>
```

*Script*

```
$scope.list = ["JHON", "Tom", "Dove", "Sam"]

$scope.selectedItem = "Dove";
$scope.activeMenu = function(ls){
    $scope.selectedItem = ls;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/q67gz7d8/)

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you are trying to search Dove in your `li` markup. For that Try below code.

```
   var yourQuery  ="dove";
        $('.nav').on('click', 'li', function(){
             $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            $("li:contains('" + yourQuery + "')").addClass('active');
    });
```